# Why first network call takes more time than subsequent ones?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, google-chrome

I am trying to understand this behavior where first network call takes more than double of subsequent ones. I know that DNS resolving will not take more than 5-50ms and it happens only in the initial call. Considering this info, there shouldn’t be much difference in time taken for the first call and subsequent calls.

I have tested this behavior with some famous URLs in separate incognito windows for each with cache disabled and attached a few screenshots to support my observation below. Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Note: The readings are taken in full speed internet connection

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Chrome, you can get a timing breakdown by hovering over the time. Please show that breakdown here.

Comment: @bishop thanks for the reply. I tried that feature and understood that HTTP handshake for creating the connection is taking the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a  few experiments, I found out that `Content Download` ([browser request steps](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation)) part of the request is speeding up 1.5-2 times
This looks like a cause of [`TCP Slow Start algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#Slow_start)

As it states:

> modern browsers either open multiple connections simultaneously or reuse one connection for all files requested from a particular web server

That might be the reason for the first request to be slower than others

Also, @Vishal Vijay made a good addition:

Making initial connection handshake to the server is taking time (DNS Lookup + Initial connection + SSL). Browsers are creating Persistent Connections for HTTP requests and keep it open for some time. If any request came in for the same domain within that time, the browser will try to reuse the same connection for faster response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here server-side caching is not the problem, assume that you are trying to access a file which is already cached in CDN server or some API which doesn't have any layer of caching. First time when you call those resource from a new browser or an incognito window, that first API call will take more time than subsequent ones. 

Here assume that the server is in ideal condition for all request, where something in browser or network layer is adding an extra latency for the first request. We are trying to understand what it is.

Comment: Hey @VishalVijay. Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer, hope that will be helpful

Comment: It's the difference between initial domain lookup time, so if you use a domain  prefetch in the html you can see both requests will take similar time

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov You new update looks like valid. Let me read about those

Comment: @AnoopMc  Agree, DNS resolving is a reason for the difference, which we already mentioned in the question

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov you are almost right. After looking more in-depth in Chrome, understood that making initial connection handshake to the server is taking time (DNS Lookup + Initial connection + SSL). And understood that, browsers are creating *Persistent Connections* for HTTP requests and keep it open for some time. If any request came in for the same domain within that time, the browser will try to reuse the same connection for faster response.

Thanks

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov Please remove the initial section of the answer. Also, please tweak the answer based on my last comment. Then we'll accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: @VishalVijay thank you for bringing your findings here. This is a nice addition to the original post. I've included them in my answer

Answer (score 8):

In some cases it might be server-side cache mechanism causing subsequent request to process faster, but let's just talk about the browser-side stuffs.

When you hover on the waterfall 'blocks' you will get the time details:
[image: Chrome Network Waterfall]

Here is a quick reference for each of the phases (from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation)):

> - **Queueing**. The browser queues requests when:
>
>   - There are higher priority requests.
>   - There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
>   - The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache
> - **Stalled**. The request could be stalled for any of the reasons described in Queueing.
> - **DNS Lookup**. The browser is resolving the request's IP address.
> - **Proxy negotiation**. The browser is negotiating the request with a proxy server.
> - **Request sent**. The request is being sent.
> - **ServiceWorker Preparation**. The browser is starting up the service worker.
> - **Request to ServiceWorker**. The request is being sent to the service worker.
> - **Waiting (TTFB)**. The browser is waiting for the first byte of a response. TTFB stands for Time To First Byte. This timing includes 1
>     round trip of latency and the time the server took to prepare the
>     response.
> - **Content Download**. The browser is receiving the response.
> - **Receiving Push**. The browser is receiving data for this response via HTTP/2 Server Push.
> - **Reading Push**. The browser is reading the local data previously received.

So what's difference between the first and subsequent requests in traditional HTTP/1.1 scenario?

- **DNS Lookup**: It might take more time to resolve DNS for the first request. Subsequent requests will resolve a lot faster using browser DNS cache.
- **Waiting (TTFB)**: The first request have to establish TCP connecting to the server. Due to HTTP keep-alive mechanism, subsequent requests to the same server will reuse the existing TCP connection to prevent another TCP handshake, thus reducing three round-trip time compared the first request.
- **Content Download**: Due to TCP slow start, the first request will need more time to download content. Since subsequent requests will reuse the TCP connection, when the TCP window scaled up, the content will be downloaded much faster than the first request.

Thus generally subsequent requests should be much faster than the first request. Actually this leads to a common network optimization strategy: Use as few domains as possible for your website.

HTTP/2 even introduces multiplexing to better reuse a single TCP connection. That's why HTTP/2 will give a performance boost in modern front end world, where we deploy tons of small assets on the CDN servers.